# Trying to access my parcelable object sent from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This is my `onitemclick` which I use for when I want to start the new activity (Called DynamicEvents), and at this point I want to send my object of type `Clubs` that comes from `db.get(map.get(position));`

**I now want to be able to access the object that I have sent across in my `DynamicEvents` Class**

This is my onItemClick method from my `ListSample` Class

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Clubs mymeeting = db.get(map.get(position));
                Intent i = new Intent();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("my meeting", mymeeting);
                i.putExtras(b);
                i.setClass(ListSample.this, DynamicEvents.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }           
        });
```

and at the moment I have no code in my DynamicEvents class, I have tried a few things, however most seem a bit too long winded and use `.getIntent` which eclipse wants me to write my own method for?

For my `DynamicEvents` class what should I be implmenting?
Any sample code of being able to access the object or any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Thought I would add this, this is an example of the code I have tried.
and as i said it uses .getIntent

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
     meeting = b.getParcelable("my meeting");
```

Comment: so what is the problem?post your DynamicEvents class

Comment: public class DynamicEvents  {
 Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();{
 Object meeting;
 if(b!=null)
      meeting = b.getParcelable("my meeting");
 } 
}

But the .getIntent is not a recognised method (This is an example i found when searching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dynamic events activity. `getIntent` is a method of your activity class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()

```
   public class DynamicEvents extends Activity
   {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
           Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
           Meeting meeting = b.getParcelable("my meeting");   
     } 
   }
```